# How to resolve error cannot find symbol class for Retention and IntDef?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want a function that accepts only 2 values, say *one* and *two*. I could use an enum for it but for Android, using constants (`@IntRef`) is considered to be better.

So I did this:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@IntDef({TYPE_ONE, TYPE_TWO})
public @interface InputTypes {
    int TYPE_ONE = 0;
    int TYPE_TWO = 1;
}
```

But on building APK I am getting the following errors:

> error: cannot find symbol class Retention
>   error: cannot find symbol class IntDef`

P.S. I tried cleaning the project, invalidating cache many times. (Import statements have also been added)

> Android Studio version: 3.0.0
>   minSdkVersion = 11
>   targetSdkVersion = 25
>   compileSdkVersion = 25
>   buildToolsVersion = '24.0.2'

Edit:

> Java version : 8

Comment: did you import `java.lang.annotation.Retention` and `java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy` ?

Comment: @ChrisGong Yes, I did.

Comment: Are using java 8?

Answer (score 0):

`SuppressLint` is since Added in API level **16**, so you need to upgrade to API level 16.
Another solution is to add `appcompat-v7` to your project ***build.gradle*** like the bellow :

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    ...
```